# How to make Dojo as generic while submitting a form?

Tags: ajax, post, dojo

I have the following dojo (ver 1.9) code:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/request", "dojo/dom-form"],
    function(dom, on, request, domForm){

        var form = dom.byId('user_login');
        var selectedTabId = showIdOfSelectedTab();

        // Attach the onsubmit event handler of the form
        on(form, "submit", function(evt){

            // prevent the page from navigating after submit
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();

            // Post the data to the server
            request.post("login1.php", {
                // Send the username and password
                data: domForm.toObject("user_login"),
                // Wait 2 seconds for a response
                timeout: 2000

            }).then(function(response) {
                dom.byId(selectedTabId).innerHTML = response;
            });
        });
    }
);
```

And html below:

```
<form name="user_login" id="user_login">
    User name: <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" /><br />
    <button id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to make the above dojo code as generic by sending the post action (login1.php) and the form id (i.e., user_login). I tried several ways but I could not achieve it.

Please let me know if any of you have idea.

Thanks in advance.

-Uday

Comment: Not seeing anything standing out looking at the code. What do you mean by, 'could not achieve it', and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is the demo drom the dojo Tutorial right?

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/ajax/

Did you get any Errormessages?

So let's see.

1. Have you load the dojo libary correct? If not, the widgets can't be loaded. 
   Must be somthing like:

   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js">
2. Check the path to the login1.php.
   If it's in another Folder than your code the path must be something like "../myfolder /myphp/login1.php"

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Hi MiBrock, It is working perfect as itz own way. But I want to send the login1.php and user_login as parameters to a function. So a single function can be used in the entire project's form submission. -Uday.

Comment: So you want to do somthing like this: var pathToPhp = "login1.php"; var user = dom.byId("user_name").innerHTML; sampleFunction(pathToPhp, user); , right?